# Action Sheet on front camera not responding

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I have set an action sheet which returns 3 options (take photo, choose from galery and cancel) when taking a photo, the front camera appears and takes the photo perfectly, but the problem is when I take again a photo, it doesn't show me the frotn facing camera, it shows me the back camera.
This is the code:

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{   
    CustomImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[CustomImagePickerController alloc] init];
    [imagePicker setDelegate:self];
    [imagePicker setAllowsEditing:YES];

    if(buttonIndex == 0) {
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
        [imagePicker setCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront];
    } else if(buttonIndex == 1) {
        [imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
    }
```

i have more things in the code, but the main action is set there.

Is something wrong?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reason why it could be happening is when you start camera first time then  `AVCaptureSession`  in background might be  kept running after the dismiss of the controller. So the next time you presented it, it tried to add the front camera  but it was busy, so it went to the next available (the back camera), interrupted itself (thus freeing the previous one) and so on.  If you are using ARC then it is good idea to use `imagePicker` as property to the class where you are using it.

OR check everytime for the camera device

```
if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        {
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            [imagePicker setCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront];
        }

    }
```

Comment: I try your code and it doesn't solve it :( yes Im using it. How can I check everytime ?

Comment: make your `imagepicker` as property  to the class

Comment: Like this? @property (nonatomic, retain) UIImagePickerController *imagePicker;

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    CustomImagePickerController *imagePicker = [[CustomImagePickerController alloc] init];
[imagePicker setDelegate:self];
[imagePicker setAllowsEditing:YES];

    if(buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        if([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera])
        {
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
            [imagePicker setCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront];
        }
        else
        {
            imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
            [imagePicker setCameraDevice:UIImagePickerControllerCameraDeviceFront];
        }

         [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil ];

    }
    else if (buttonIndex==1)
    {
        imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum;
        [self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil ];

    }
}
```

Comment: in the "[self presentViewController:imagePicker animated:YES completion:nil];" it shows me a warning that tells me: instance method not found (return types defaults to id)